# What setting will prevent "vi" to show the editing window after exiting?

Tags: vi

I tried to search the answer, but maybe I'm phrasing the question wrong, I couldn't find it.

So, in my own Linux environment, when I exit "vi", the content of the editing window stays in the shell window. I cannot just scroll up to see the previous commands I typed before entering "vi". I've been in some environment (as a different user) where once I exit "vi", the vi command just shows as one regular command line following all the earlier commands I typed. I tried to look for the setting for that behavior, which I liked, but I couldn't. Can someone please help me?

Comment: That's strange. I've never had this problem... You can clear the screen, if you'd like, with `CTRL-L`. It's a temporary fix.

Comment: There are `t_ti` and `t_te` settings but I unfortunately only see results for how to do the reverse of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a `vi` setting per se; it is in the terminfo entry you use (`$TERM`).  Check on what your other user has set for `$TERM`, and compare that with what you have set.  Then, either change your TERM value, or modify the terminal entry you do use.  `infocmp` decompiles terminal entries; `tic` compiles them.  You can create your own directory to hold the entry if you can't modify the system one (or while you are testing your modifications):

```
mkdir $HOME/terminfo
export TERMINFO=$HOME/terminfo
tic -o $TERMINFO new.terminfo.src
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that it's not another user's env; it was my own. When I'm in a gnome terminal via VNC, $TERM is automatically set to be xterm. I get the behavior I want there. When I'm in a Putty session, $TERM=screen. Does that mean that there is no way I can get the same behavior when I'm using Putty? I don't think it makes sense to set $TERM to be screen in Putty though.

Comment: @May: take a look at the settings Putty allows.  It may well include 'which terminal to emulate'.  If so, consider setting it to emulate 'xterm'; that will then set TERM=xterm and everything will be uniform.  Failing that, you would need to find and decompile the terminfo entry for 'screen', and then modify it to include the 'clear screen on exit' option - I forget what the code for that is.

Comment: What was the setting?